# .change() doesn't trigger after jQuery UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

Once I convert a select field using jQuery UI, change event doesn't work.

```
$(function() {
    $( "#speed" ).selectmenu();
    $( "#files" ).selectmenu();
    $( "#number" )
      .selectmenu()
      .selectmenu( "menuWidget" )
        .addClass( "overflow" );
    $( "#speed" ).change(function(){
      console.log("change");
    });
  });
```

If `$( "#speed" ).selectmenu();` is commented out then the change event works perfectly? Why is this happening?.

http://jsbin.com/debem/1/edit?js,console,output

Comment: See plugin DOC, use specific change event

Comment: what do you mean by specific change event

Comment: I meant, you should read DOC

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you should be using the change event of the ui select menu look **[here](http://api.jqueryui.com/selectmenu/#event-change)**

```
$( "#speed" ).selectmenu({
       change: function( event, ui ) {
          console.log('change');
        }
   });
```

Answer (score 2):

selectmenu needs to have a change function passed in as a parameter when initialized or you have to listen for `selectmenuchange` event as described [in the selectmenu api docs](http://api.jqueryui.com/selectmenu/#event-change)

Edit: updated your JS Bin to watch the correct event, http://jsbin.com/gogenuhaso/1/edit?js,console,output